# Dust iterate over array

Tags: javascript, dust.js, kraken.js

I am using Kraken.js, dust, mongoose. I have the following object that I get from MongoDB with mongoose.

```
artist = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxx"),
    "first_name" : "myName",
    "last_name" : "myLastname",
    "description" : "Sample Description here",
    "thumbnail" : "thumbnail.jpg",
    "works" : [ 
        "art1.jpg", 
        "art2.jpg"
    ]
}
```

The name of the whole model I send to my template is artist (singular).

I want to generate `image` tag for each member of `works`.

```
<img src="art1.jpg" />
<img src="art2.jpg" />
```

I have tried following snippets and it's not working

```
{#.}
    <img src="./../../images/artists/{.works}" alt="" />
{/.}

{#artist.works}
    <img src="./../../images/artists/{.works}" alt="" />
{/.artist.works}
```

and it prints " "

Genuinely appreciate your help

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: According to the [tutorial](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial) you need to use sections to loop.

Comment: `artist.works` is an *Array* - therefore you can iterate over it

Comment: @JaromandaX you mean like this => ` {#artist.works}
                                                <img src="./../../images/artists/{.}" alt="" />
                                        {/artist.works}`

Comment: lets assume you know more about dust than I do

Comment: @JamieJamier That is correct.

Comment: @thefourtheye the problem is that doesn't work 

Comment: "it doesn't work" ... so, is there an error? does it produce something unexpected? does it reprogram your microwave? exactly what do you observe?

Comment: it prints empty string, " " when I inspect

Comment: @JamieJamier Check my answer. If the context being passed is the `artist` object then you have to iterate the `works` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL/DR:**

1. If the context being passed is the `artist` object, then you need to iterate the `works` object only.
2. If the context being passed is an object which contains the `artist` object, then you need to iterate with `artist.works`.

This is the working version of your example.

```js
var data = {
  "artist": {
    "first_name": "myName",
    "last_name": "myLastname",
    "description": "Sample Description here",
    "thumbnail": "thumbnail.jpg",
    "works": [
      "art1.jpg",
      "art2.jpg"
    ]
  }
};

var compiled = dust.compile('<ul>{#artist.works}<li><a href="{.}" >{.}</a></li>{/artist.works}</ul>', 'hello');
// Register the template with Dust
dust.loadSource(compiled);
// Render the template
dust.render('hello', data, function(err, out) {
  // `out` contains the rendered output.
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dustjs-linkedin/2.7.5/dust-full.js"></script>

<div id="output" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) ,  that results in https://ibb.co/bYSpUd   ,  https://ibb.co/mK6ipd

Comment: First image me writing the code, second image is the result in browser

Comment: @JamieJamier Okay. Since the context is not the `artist` object, you need to write it like this `{#artist.works}<img src="./../../images/artists/{.}" alt="" />{/artist.works}`.

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work, I came up with the same solution but idk why it doesn't work

Comment: @JamieJamier I have updated the answer to show that `{#artist.works}` works. I am out of ideas now, unless I see the actual code. GL.

Comment: The dust code in @thefourtheye's answer should work as it is; However, you'd need to change your mongoose document to a json 'model' before you use it for rendering dust template. Calling `toJSON` on the mongoose document should return a proper json object you can use. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON

Comment: This is the object I get when I console the result of querying MongoDB with Mongoose => `{
  "artist": {
    "_id": 123,
    "first_name": "MyName",
    "last_name": "MyLastName",
    "description": "Something here",
    "thumbnail": "Thumbnail.jpg",
    "works": [
      "JC1.jpg",
      "JC2.jpg"
    ]
  }
}` sorry I couldn't indent it properly here